# Run-time error 3075

Tags: ms-access, vba

I do wish to create a multiple filter function in VBA to sort a subform from controls on the main form.

Here is my code

```
Dim strWhere As String
Dim lngLen As Long
Const conJetDate = "\#dd\/mm\/yyyy\#"

If Not IsNull(Me.PerPNum) Then
    strWhere = "([PNum] = " & Me.PerPNum & ") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.PerPPro) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([PPro] =  " & Me.PerPPro & ") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.PerPRev) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([PRev] = " & Me.PerPRev & ") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.DateStart) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([TaskStart] >= " & Format(Me.DateStart, conJetDate) & ") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.DateEnd) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([TaskEnd] < " & Format(Me.DateEnd + 1, conJetDate) & ") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.PerDesi) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([UInit] = " & Me.PerDesi & ") AND "
End If

lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen <= 0 Then
    MsgBox "No criteria", vbInformation, "Nothing to do."
Else

Debug.Print strWhere

    Me.Sub_Desi_Schedule.Form.Filter = strWhere
    Me.Sub_Desi_Schedule.Form.FilterOn = True
End If
```

However I keep getting a run-time error 3075 (Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression.

I can see my variables in the error message though.

I know it's my query expression that is malformed. But I can't figure what.

Comment: You never actually strip off the trailing `AND` in your query.  You set a variable equal to the length (`lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5`), but never update your `strWhere` variable.  Simply checking your `Debug.Print strWhere` should have confirmed this.  Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: It is indeed always ending with " AND ". The piece of code
    lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
    If lngLen <= 0 Then
        MsgBox "No criteria", vbInformation, "Nothing to do."
    Else
Is supposed to get rid of that tail

Comment: I don't think you understand the code you wrote.  `lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5` simply sets the variable `lngLen` equal to the length of the `strWhere` variable, minus 5.  At no point do you strip off the trailing `AND` clause from `strWhere`, which is the cause of your problem.

Comment: How should it look like ? If I would understand this error, do you think I would be here asking ? ;-)

Comment: Third time:  strip off the trailing `AND` in your query; [it's your basic SQL `WHERE` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx).  You even check for it here:  `lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5`.  Just take the `LEFT` of `strWhere`, using `lngLen`.  Your entire query makes you vulnerable to SQL injection, though; you're better off using a parameterized query.

Comment: All right,
Here is what I tried
Me.Sub_Desi_Schedule.Form.Filter = Len(strWhere) - 5

and

Me.Sub_Desi_Schedule.Form.Filter = lngLen

in both cases, the error is gone. However no filters are applied.

Regarding SQL INjection, this is NOT a public database and it's using a MS Access front end.

Comment: The string "lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5" is there to remove the trailing AND. But obviously it does not do it. I hope someone can help me with this. I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I feel compelled to answer this because it seems like you're fundamentally not getting something, or more than one thing, and I'm not getting through with my comments.

I don't know if you're just copying and pasting code without understanding it, or in such a rush that you aren't taking the time to understand it.

Let's start with:

> The piece of code `lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5 If lngLen <= 0 Then MsgBox "No criteria", vbInformation, "Nothing to do." Else` Is supposed to get rid of that tail

No, it's not.

```
lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen <= 0 Then
    MsgBox "No criteria", vbInformation, "Nothing to do."
Else
    Debug.Print strWhere

    Me.Sub_Desi_Schedule.Form.Filter = strWhere
    Me.Sub_Desi_Schedule.Form.FilterOn = True
End If
```

does two things.  It sets `lngLen` equal to the length of your `strWhere` variable, minus 5.  It then checks to see if the length is less than or equal to 0.

If your `strWhere` statement was...

```
 ([PNum] = 27) AND
```

... you would set `lngLen` equal to 13.

Since 13 is not less than or equal to zero, we move into your `ELSE` statement, and set the filter.

```
Me.Sub_Desi_Schedule.Form.Filter = strWhere
```

Which becomes

```
Me.Sub_Desi_Schedule.Form.Filter = "([PNum] = 27) AND "
```

See?  You've *still* got your trailing `AND` because you never update your `strWhere` variable.

> Here is what I tried `Me.Sub_Desi_Schedule.Form.Filter = Len(strWhere) - 5` and `Me.Sub_Desi_Schedule.Form.Filter = lngLen` in both cases, the error is gone. However no filters are applied.

So now you're just doing

```
Me.Sub_Desi_Schedule.Form.Filter = Len(strWhere) - 5`
```

which is the equivalent of

```
Me.Sub_Desi_Schedule.Form.Filter = 13
```

That doesn't accomplish anything.  You're setting the filter equal to the length of the variable, not the actual `strWhere` variable.  This should have been apparent if you put any break points in your code.

I recommended using `LEFT` to trim down your string, like this:

```
strWhere = LEFT(strWhere, lngLen)
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: @AndreArsenault If you encounter any more problems with this, please show us what `Debug.Print strWhere` shows you when you get that 3075 error.

Comment: HandsUp, Here is the debug result with the "strWhere = LEFT(strWhere, lngLen)" : ([PNum] = 19239) AND ([PPro] =  0) AND

Comment: I got it to work with strWhere = LEFT(strWhere, lngLen) 
Thanks for the patronizing help...............